# Angular unit test spyOn not detecting my call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, spy

I've got a problem with a unit test I can't solve.
Here is my test :

```
fit('should call the alert service in case something went wrong getting the list of files', async(() => {
     spyOn(this.component.alert, 'error');
     this.component.onInputChange('error');
     this.fixture.whenStable().then((() => {
         expect(this.component.alert.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('an error occured');
     }));
}));
```

And here is the part of the component I'm testing :

```
private onInputChange (search: string) {
    const that = this;
    this.translateFileService.getVideoFiles(search)
        .then(files => (files.length) ? this.files = files : '')
        .catch(this.alert.error.bind(that));
}
```

For testing purpose, the translateFileService is mocked like this :

```
class TranslateFileServiceMock {

    getVideoFiles (search: string): Promise<IcoFile[]> {
        const fileList = [
            IcoFile.fromJSON({id: '0', label: 'test0', creationTime: '2017-07-01'}),
            IcoFile.fromJSON({id: '1', label: 'test1', creationTime: '2017-07-02'}),
            IcoFile.fromJSON({id: '2', label: 'test2', creationTime: '2017-07-03'}),
        ];

        return new Promise<IcoFile[]>((resolve, reject) => {
            if (search === 'error') return reject('an error occured');
            return resolve(fileList.filter(f => f.label.includes(search)));
        });
    }

}
```

The onInputChange method call the alert service representated by the alert property in my component.
The alert service is not mocked, it is the real service. The call to it's error method is actually made, I already verified. But my test is always failing : the spy is not detecting my call.

I always got the following error :

```
Expected spy error to have been called with [ 'an error occured' ] but it was never called.
```

I don't know what to do. I tried everything I know about.
At first I thought my call was not properly detected because I was mocking my alert service, but even with the real one it's not working.

I hope you can help, thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: Done, tell me if you need something more :)

Comment: Why are you using `this` in `this.component`, `this.fixture`?

Comment: Because they are defined in a beforeEach function where I configure my testing module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems `this.fixture.whenStable().then` is executed before `catch` handler. I would use `fakeAsync` with `tick`

```typescript
fit('should call ...', fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(component.alert, 'error');
  component.onInputChange('error');
  tick();
  expect(component.alert.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('an error occured');
}));
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/i6J3izp1DTnDGUM1qZ4m?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works ! Do you have any reason why the "this.fixture.whenStable().then" is executed before the catch handler ? I though the "whenstable" method goal was to wait for any asynchronous task to finish before executing some code.

Comment: I also thought so. But if we will investigate it deeper we can notice that `tick()` is running `flushMicrotasks`. It simulates the asynchronous passage of time. While whenStable checks `isStable` status `this._isStable && !this.ngZone.hasPendingMacrotasks` but during your test there is no changes for isStable status because `ngZone.onUnstable ` event is never called. Working with tests in angular is always a trick :)

Comment: Indeed, it looks tricky for now Still it seems quite strange that the onUnstable event is never triggered when a function returning a promise is called. Thanks for the explanation anyway :)