# How to correctly call function from unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

When running a code coverage test it says that the function clearAllValues is not being executed in the test but I am calling this function in my tests below

[image: code coverage]

tests

```
it('clearAllValues should be called by click', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'clearAllValues');
  const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.clearAllValuesBtn')).nativeElement;
  button.click();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.clearAllValues).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.value).toEqual('');
    expect(component.allowReset).toEqual(false);
    expect(component.term).toEqual('');
  });
});

it('should call clearAllValues function', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'clearAllValues');
  component.clearAllValues();
  expect(component.clearAllValues).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

component

```
clearAllValues = () => {
  this.value = '';
  this.allowReset = false;
  this.term = '';
}
```

Comment: Check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502462/angular-unit-test-spyon-not-detecting-my-call

Comment: Did you try `fixture.detectChanges();` before the `expect`tations?

Answer (score 2):

> In unit testing, while testing a particular method/function we may not always want to call through all the other dependent methods/functions. Jasmine provides the `spyOn()` function for such purposes.

As per this definition, we only need to use a `spy` for your first test. When the button is clicked, we just want to find out whether `clearAllValues` was called, We're not bothered about what the function actually does. That part can be tested separately. See the [docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) to know when you need to use spies.

In your first test `clearAllValues should be called by click`, you need to do just that, i.e. check if `clearAllValues` was called. You need to use a spy for this test to find out if the function was called or not.

```js
it('clearAllValues should be called by click', () => {
    const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.clearAllValuesBtn')).nativeElement;
    spyOn(component, 'clearAllValues');
    button.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.clearAllValues).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Then when you are actually testing `clearAllValues`, that's when you need to check whether your variables have been set or not.

```js
it('should clear values when clearAllValues is called', () => {
    component.clearAllValues();
    expect(component.value).toEqual('');
    expect(component.allowReset).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.term).toEqual('');
});
```

Comment: The `clearAllValues should be called by click'` does not work